# Подскажите, как закончить цикл?

Tags: python, циклы, while

```
while True:
    name = input("да или нет?")
    if name == "да":
        print("Погнали!")        
    elif name == "нет":
        print("Как хочешь.Пока.")       
    else:
        print("выберите одно из перечисленных действий.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    elif name == "нет":
        print("Как хочешь.Пока.") 
        break # вот так выходят из циклов
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно цикл не делать бесконечным:

```
name = ''
while name not in ['да', 'нет']:
    name = input('Введите "да" или "нет"?')
    if name == 'да':
        print('Погнали!')        
    elif name == 'нет':
        print('Как хочешь... Пока!')
```

Comment: после ответа "да" он опять задает вопрос, т.е. цикл не завершается а продолжает работать и только на ответ "нет" цикл завершился :)

Comment: @МишаМ нужно, что закончился при ввводе как Да, так и Нет? измените условие выхода: while name not in ['да', 'нет']: